# How to define if table is a good candidate for a clustered columnstore index?

Tags: clustered-index, sql-server-2014, columnstore

I have read ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088.aspx),[here](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/feature/SQL-Server-2014-columnstore-index-the-good-the-bad-and-the-clustered) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2014/06/16/from-the-mvps-updated-column-store-indexes-in-sql-server-2014.aspx)) about clustered columnstore indexes introduced in SQL Server 2014. Basically, now:

- Column store indexes can be updatable
- Table schema can be modified (without drop column store indexes)
- Structure of the base table can be columnar
- Space saved by compression effects (with a column store index, you
  can save between 40 to 50 percent of initial space used for the
  table)

In addition, they support:

- Row mode and Batch mode processing
- BULK INSERT statement
- More data types

AS I have understood there are some restrictions, like:

1. Unsupported data types
2. Other indexes cannot be created

But as it is said:

> With a clustered column store index, all filter possibilities are
>   already covered; Query Processor, using Segment Elimination, will be
>   able to consider only the segments required by the query clauses. On
>   the columns where it cannot apply the Segment Elimination, all scans
>   will be faster than B-Tree index scans because data are compressed so
>   less I/O operations will be required.

I am interested in the following:

- Does the statement above say that a clustered column store index is always better for extracting data than a B-Tree index when a lot of duplicated values exist?
- What about the performance between clustered column store index and non-clustered B-Tree `covering` index, when the table has many columns for example?
- Can I have a combination of clustered and non-clustered columnstores indexes on one table?
- And most importantly, can anyone tell how to determine whether a table is a good candidate for a columned stored index?

It is said that the best candidates are tables for which update/delete/insert operations are not performed often. For example, I have a table with storage size above 17 GB (about 70 millions rows) and new records are inserted and deleted constantly. On the other hand, a lot of queries using its columns are performed. Or I have a table with storage size about 40 GB (about 60 millions rows) with many inserts performed each day - it is not queried often but I want to reduce its size.

I know the answer is mostly in running production tests but before that I need to pick the better candidates.

Answer (score 3):

One of the most important restrictions for Clustered Columnstore is their locking, you can find some details over here: http://www.nikoport.com/2013/07/07/clustered-columnstore-indexes-part-8-locking/

Regarding your questions:

1) Does the statement above say that a clustered column store index is always better for extracting data then a B-Tree index when a lot of duplicated values exist

- Not only duplicates are faster scanned by Batch Mode, but for data reading the mechanisms for Columnstore Indexes are more effective, when reading all data out of a Segment.

2) What about the performance between clustered column store index and non-clustered B-Tree covering index, when the table has many columns for example

- Columnstore Index has a significantly better compression than Page or Row, available for the Row Store, Batch Mode shall make the biggest difference on the processing side and as already mentioned even reading of the equally-sized pages & extents should be faster for Columnstore Indexes

3) Can I have a combination of clustered and non clustered columnstores indexes on one table

- No, at the moment this is impossible.

4) ... can anyone tell how to define if a table is a good candidate for a columned stored index?

- Any table which you are scanning & processing in big amounts (over 1 million rows), or **maybe** even whole table with over 100K scanned entirely might be a candidate to consider.
  There are some restrictions on the used technologies related to the table where you want to build Clustered Columnstore indexes, here is a query that I am using:

---

```
select object_schema_name( t.object_id ) as 'Schema'
, object_name (t.object_id) as 'Table'
, sum(p.rows) as 'Row Count'
, cast( sum(a.total_pages) * 8.0 / 1024. / 1024 
    as decimal(16,3)) as 'size in GB'
    , (select count(*) from sys.columns as col
    where t.object_id = col.object_id ) as 'Cols Count'
, (select count(*) 
        from sys.columns as col
        join sys.types as tp
        on col.system_type_id = tp.system_type_id
        where t.object_id = col.object_id and 
             UPPER(tp.name) in ('VARCHAR','NVARCHAR') 
   ) as 'String Columns'
, (select sum(col.max_length) 
        from sys.columns as col
        join sys.types as tp
        on col.system_type_id = tp.system_type_id
        where t.object_id = col.object_id 
  ) as 'Cols Max Length'
, (select count(*) 
        from sys.columns as col
        join sys.types as tp
        on col.system_type_id = tp.system_type_id
        where t.object_id = col.object_id and 
             (UPPER(tp.name) in ('TEXT','NTEXT','TIMESTAMP','HIERARCHYID','SQL_VARIANT','XML','GEOGRAPHY','GEOMETRY') OR
              (UPPER(tp.name) in ('VARCHAR','NVARCHAR') and (col.max_length = 8000 or col.max_length = -1)) 
             )
   ) as 'Unsupported Columns'
, (select count(*)
        from sys.objects
        where type = 'PK' AND parent_object_id = t.object_id ) as 'Primary Key'
, (select count(*)
        from sys.objects
        where type = 'F' AND parent_object_id = t.object_id ) as 'Foreign Keys'
, (select count(*)
        from sys.objects
        where type in ('UQ','D','C') AND parent_object_id = t.object_id ) as 'Constraints'
, (select count(*)
        from sys.objects
        where type in ('TA','TR') AND parent_object_id = t.object_id ) as 'Triggers'
, t.is_tracked_by_cdc as 'CDC'
, t.is_memory_optimized as 'Hekaton'
, t.is_replicated as 'Replication'
, coalesce(t.filestream_data_space_id,0,1) as 'FileStream'
, t.is_filetable as 'FileTable'
from sys.tables t
inner join sys.partitions as p 
    ON t.object_id = p.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units as a 
    ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
where p.data_compression in (0,1,2) -- None, Row, Page
group by t.object_id, t.is_tracked_by_cdc,  t.is_memory_optimized, t.is_filetable, t.is_replicated, t.filestream_data_space_id
having sum(p.rows) > 1000000
order by sum(p.rows) desc
```